# Symbols in Gnuplot label

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Code in terminal qt and gnuplot 5.0

```
plot x; set xlabel 'Magnetic field {/Symbol Mu}_0'
```

which works in gnuplot prompt. 
However, `{/Symbol mu}_0` is not working in Commandline script

```
`/usr/local/bin/gnuplot -e "plot x; set xlabel 'Magnetic field {/Symbol m}_0 H / mT'`;
```

I get

```
gdImageStringFT: No character set found while printing string mu with font Symbol
```

**How can you write the symbol with underscore in gnuplot label?**

Comment: Please give a full, minimal example (including the terminal).

Comment: You are missing the terminal you are using. With `qt` and version 5.0 it works fine if I use `set xlabel "{/Symbol m}"` to get a µ character. And likewise it works fine to use `set xlabel "{/Symbol m}_0"` to get a µ with an subscripted zero.

Comment: You are right! Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: In my script, this does not work: `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot -e "set xlabel 'Magnetic field {/Symbol m}\_0 H / mT'"` Some problem with those " and '. Yes, I get again the error `gdImageStringFT: No character set found while printing string m with font Symbol`.

Comment: If you want to get a subscripted 0 you must remove that backslash

Comment: Yes, I did it but still same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76921/discussion-between-christoph-and-masi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get µ character with subscript zero, use either a utf8-encoded label

```
gnuplot -p -e "set encoding utf8; set xlabel 'Magnetic field µ₀ H / mT'; plot x"
```

or

```
gnuplot -p -e "set xlabel 'Magnetic field {/Symbol m}_0 H / mT'; plot x"
```

Comment: In the first one, I get a square in place of zero but \mu correctly. In the second one, I get square for whole symbol.

Comment: This one works `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot -p -e "set encoding utf8; set xlabel 'Magnetic field µ_0 H / mT';`